# javax.el.ELException: The class [java.lang.Number] must be public, non-abstract and not an interface

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I am getting the "Error 500: javax.el.ELException: The class [java.lang.Number] must be public, non-abstract and not an interface" on my jsp page.

here are the logs.

```
000001f8 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: An exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet [/WEB-INF/pages/tpl/docDetail.jsp] in application [gsa]. Exception created : [javax.el.ELException: The class [java.lang.Number] must be public, non-abstract and not an interface
        at javax.el.ImportHandler.findClass(ImportHandler.java:231)
        at javax.el.ImportHandler.resolveClass(ImportHandler.java:185)
        at javax.servlet.jsp.el.ScopedAttributeELResolver.getValue(ScopedAttributeELResolver.java:140)
        at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:80)
        at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:815)
        at com.ibm._jsp._docDetail._jspx_meth_c_out_1(_docDetail.java:311)
        at com.ibm._jsp._docDetail._jspService(_docDetail.java:130)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:220)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1124)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1390)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:196)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1085)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:263)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:398)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:318)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:241)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
```

Here is my docDetail.jsp page code:

```html
<%-- --------------- LANGUAGE --------------- --%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%-- --------------- TAGLIBS --------------- --%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic" %>
<%-- --------------- IMPORTS --------------- --%>

<%@page import="java.util.List,java.util.Iterator,
                com.vw.gsasearch.domain.tpl.model.TplProcess" %> 
                
            

<c:set var="cssURL">
  <bean:message key="css.elsa.vw"  />
</c:set>
<c:set var="cssURL">
  <html:rewrite page="${cssURL}" />
</c:set>

<html>
<head>
  <LINK href='<c:out value="${cssURL}" />' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <style>
  td{
        color: #000000; 
        font-size: 10pt; 
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
        text-decoration: none;  
   }
  </style>  
  
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      var g_count;
      var g_position;
   function disableButtons() {
  
    if (top['barFs']) {
      g_count = '<c:out value="${Number}"/>';
      g_position = '<c:out value="${Position}"/>';
      if (!(top['barFs'].disableButtons)) {
            window.setTimeout("delay100()", 100);
          } else {
            top['barFs'].disableButtons(g_count, g_position);
          }
    }
  
   }
   function delay100() {
        if (!(top['barFs'].disableButtons)) {
          window.setTimeout("delay100()", 100);
        } else {
          top['barFs'].disableButtons(g_count, g_position);
        }
 
      }
      
  </script>
</head>

<body class="elsaBackground_light" onload="disableButtons();">
<form>
 <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
   <%-- <td><bean:message key="process.pid" bundle="TPL" />:</td>
    <td><select class="readonlyInput" readonly="readonly" name="kdnr" size="1">
    <option>&nbsp;</option></td> --%>
    <td><bean:message key="process.revised"  />: </td>
    <td><c:out value="${procedure.changeDate}" /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </body>
 
 <%-- remove session atrribute --%> 
 <%--<c:remove var="procedure" scope="session" /> --%> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your variable name to comply the [Java naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) and this problem shall disappear.

The culprit is here:

```
<c:out value="${Number}"/>
```

And in EL 3.0's new "import constants" feature:

```
at javax.el.ImportHandler.findClass(ImportHandler.java:231) 
at javax.el.ImportHandler.resolveClass(ImportHandler.java:185)
```

In Java, variable names start with lowercase and class names start with uppercase. Since EL 3.0, anything from `java.lang.*` package is implicitly imported in EL scope, so also `java.lang.Number`. In other words, when you reference `${Number}` in EL, which matches `java.lang.Number` class, then it attempts to load it which it couldn't do because it's `abstract`.

But this is after all not your intent. You clearly intented to reference a custom variable which you just misnomed `Number` instead of `number`.

As to why in earth Apache EL attempts to resolve `${Number}` like that while it doesn't have any constants at all is a different problem. You'd best [report an issue to Tomcat guys](http://tomcat.apache.org/bugreport.html).

Comment: It does not solved the issue. Still getting the same error. The application was migrated from WAS7 to WAS9 and the issue started appearing. It works fine on WAS7 with the same code.

Comment: Then you've forgotten to save or rebuild or redeploy the code after editing the variable name. Of course it works on WAS7 because that old beast uses only EL 2.1.

Comment: Then you've forgotten to rename other occurrences of `${Number}` throughout your JSP files.

Comment: If you get exactly the same error (including exactly the same stack trace) in spite of the code changes, then you aren't running the code you think you're running.

Comment: Thank You ! my issue is resolved now. Your solution worked as the code was not deployed properly.